# When I add a new field I get a null pointer

Tags: android, ormlite

I have my ORMlite service working fine. All CRUD operations work fine.
However when I add a new nullable field to my entity, the whole thing fails.  I get null pointers and the application dies.

This is the field I added:

```
@DatabaseField( canBeNull = true  )
private String newField;
```

If I drop my DB and recreate it then everything is fine.  What I would like to know is why does a simple schema change cause this?  I'm thinking ahead where a DB is full with data and I don't want a new nullable field to break it or is this to be expected?

Here's the exception:

```
W/System.err(16955): java.sql.SQLException: Unknown field 'newField' from the Android sqlite cursor, not in:[desc, name, id]
W/System.err(16955):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseResults.findColumn(AndroidDatabaseResults.java:97)
W/System.err(16955):    at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.resultToJava(FieldType.java:793)
W/System.err(16955):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.BaseMappedQuery.mapRow(BaseMappedQuery.java:60)
W/System.err(16955):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.getCurrent(SelectIterator.java:270)
```

---

Here is the exception I'm getting when I update my entity class to include the following new field.

```
@DatabaseField( canBeNull = true  )
private String newField;
```

Now seeing that if I remove the new field my test case/app works fine then it is this code that breaks things .

```
[2012-07-05 22:42:00 - WishListManager] Success!
[2012-07-05 22:42:00 - WishListManagerTest] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on device emulator-5554
[2012-07-05 22:42:00 - WishListManagerTest] Collecting test information
[2012-07-05 22:42:02 - WishListManagerTest] Sending test information to Eclipse
[2012-07-05 22:42:02 - WishListManagerTest] Running tests...
[2012-07-05 22:42:04 - WishListManagerTest] Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException'
[2012-07-05 22:42:04 - WishListManagerTest] Test run finished


07-05 21:42:02.084: I/TestRunner(16955): started: testAddDuplicateWishLists(com.tests.WishListServiceTest)
07-05 21:42:02.504: I/global(16955): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
07-05 21:42:02.524: I/global(16955): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
07-05 21:42:02.654: D/dalvikvm(16955): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4623 objects / 361912 bytes in 63ms
07-05 21:42:02.754: I/global(16955): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
07-05 21:42:02.764: I/global(16955): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
07-05 21:42:02.774: W/System.err(16955): java.sql.SQLException: Unknown field 'newField' from the Android sqlite cursor, not in:[desc, name, id]
07-05 21:42:02.784: W/System.err(16955):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseResults.findColumn(AndroidDatabaseResults.java:97)
07-05 21:42:02.784: W/System.err(16955):    at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.resultToJava(FieldType.java:793)
07-05 21:42:02.784: W/System.err(16955):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.BaseMappedQuery.mapRow(BaseMappedQuery.java:60)
07-05 21:42:02.784: W/System.err(16955):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.getCurrent(SelectIterator.java:270)
07-05 21:42:02.784: W/System.err(16955):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.nextThrow(SelectIterator.java:161)
07-05 21:42:02.784: W/System.err(16955):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:161)
07-05 21:42:02.784: W/System.err(16955):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.queryForAll(StatementExecutor.java:113)
07-05 21:42:02.784: W/System.err(16955):    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryForAll(BaseDaoImpl.java:237)
07-05 21:42:02.784: W/System.err(16955):    at com.test.db.WishListService.getAllWishLists(WishListService.java:42)
07-05 21:42:02.784: W/System.err(16955):    at com.test.WishListManagerActivity.setupListView(WishListManagerActivity.java:48)
07-05 21:42:02.784: W/System.err(16955):    at com.test.WishListManagerActivity.onStart(WishListManagerActivity.java:44)
07-05 21:42:02.784: W/System.err(16955):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
07-05 21:42:02.784: W/System.err(16955):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3781)
07-05 21:42:02.784: W/System.err(16955):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2636)
07-05 21:42:02.784: W/System.err(16955):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-05 21:42:02.794: W/System.err(16955):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-05 21:42:02.794: W/System.err(16955):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-05 21:42:02.794: W/System.err(16955):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 21:42:02.794: W/System.err(16955):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-05 21:42:02.794: W/System.err(16955):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-05 21:42:02.794: W/System.err(16955):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 21:42:02.794: W/System.err(16955):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-05 21:42:02.794: W/System.err(16955):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-05 21:42:02.794: W/System.err(16955):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-05 21:42:02.794: W/System.err(16955):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 21:42:02.804: D/AndroidRuntime(16955): Shutting down VM
07-05 21:42:02.804: W/dalvikvm(16955): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.WishListManagerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at com.test.WishListManagerActivity.setupListView(WishListManagerActivity.java:51)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at com.test.WishListManagerActivity.onStart(WishListManagerActivity.java:44)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3781)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2636)
07-05 21:42:02.814: E/AndroidRuntime(16955):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: I assume "null pointer" means a null-pointer-exception?  If so then please edit your post to show the _full_ exception.

Comment: Also, can you show the code on how you are updating the schema?

Comment: Elaborate on the pear shaped issue.

Comment: @eternalmatt "goes pear shaped" == "goes horribly wrong" in britain I guess.

Comment: Did my answer help you dude?  Please make sure to +1 and accept it if so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have my ORMlite service working fine. All CRUD operations work fine. However when I add a new nullable field to my entity, the whole thing fails.

So the [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) exception seems to me to be pretty helpful:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown field 'newField' from the Android sqlite cursor,
    not in:[desc, name, id]
```

You are trying to extract the `newField` field but it is not in the database table.  This indicates to me that you did *not* update the schema of the database.  The only fields it has in the table are `desc`, `name`, and `id`.

Either the code that is upgrading the database table has not been run or it is not working correctly.  I would take a look at the documentation page that I wrote about [how to upgrade the schema under Android](http://ormlite.com/docs/upgrade-schema).

Unfortunately, Sqlite supports only a few `ALTER TABLE` commands but `ADD COLUMN` *is* one of them.

Comment: I don't see `getHelper()` method in DatabaseHelper class, so what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I Solved This problem with the Upgrade **DB version**!
You should know when you add or remove .. in database و  should upgrade database version with!

**EXAMPLE:**

```
if the current version is = 2 after the change should be 3 ;
```